# <input> value prop is applied without re-rendering

Tags: reactjs

In [this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nw87xb), `value` prop is applied on `<input>` change even though the component isn't re-rendered:

```
const App = () => <input value="foo"/>
```

This efficiently results in read-only input. This behaviour is specific to React.

Why exactly does it work this way? The explanation from official sources is welcome.

Can we make this `<input>` work as in plain HTML without introducing `onChange`?

Comment: Denis has the correct answer, however, you should consider using controlled components, if possible. That is the recommended approach.

Comment: @Chris Absolutely. Had this problem several times when an input was left in UI as a placeholder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can, just change:

```
const App = () => <input defaultValue="foo"/>
```

for using 'Uncontrolled Component'

More information here: 
https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html

Comment: Thanks for the reference, indeed, this is about controlled/uncontrolled components.